# Application's data gets clear on running and application again gets reinstall on emulator can anyone suggest what could be the problem

Tags: android, kotlin

> Do not know what is the problem with it can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. When you will re-run the app, all the data will be lost unless you have stored the values in a database.